# Separating specific portion of a string in python

Tags: python, string, truncation, quotation-marks

I am sending information via SCPI to power supplies. I created a GUI to display its responses. One of the responses comes is an error message that is a string and it has a character, a number, a comma and a couple of words in quotation marks.
Ex:
+0,"No Error"
I need to extract just what is in the quotation marks, so what would be displayed is No Error.
I was trying to split it and then truncate it from the quotation mark, however it is never as clean as I need and I can't cut the string by simply doing _mystring[4:-1] because some of the error codes being sent back are different lengths.
ie.
-400,"Query Error"

So doing _mystring[4:-1] would display ","Query Error"

help

Comment: You should look into regular expressions https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Comment: You should include your attempts at splitting. Did you try splitting on comma then splitting on `"`?

Comment: Have you checked the docs for the [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) method?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions via the built-in `re` library are used to extract portions of strings, matching a given pattern.

Pattern explanation: `'\"(.*)\"'`

- Find a quotation mark
- *Capture* any number of characters until another quotation mark is found
- As the `.findall()` method returns *all* matches, (zero, one or more) the `[0]` index and simply returns the first match.

Documentation for the `.findall()` method is [linked here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall).

Example code:

```
import re

string = '+0,"No Error"'
re.findall('\"(.*)\"', string)[0]
```

Output:

```
'No Error'
```

---

Iterative test:

```
str1 = '+0,"No Error"'
str2 = '-400,"Query Error"'
rexp = re.compile('\"(.*)\"')

for string in [str1, str2]:
    print(rexp.findall(string)[0])
```

Output:

```
No Error
Query Error
```

Answer (score 0):

A rudimental approach using string  `split`-method:

```
response = '+0,"No Error"'

msg = response.split('"')[1]

print(msg)
#No Error
```

For a more robust solution consider to use a regular expression.

Comment: This is perfect, I was trying to mess with split earlier but wasn't getting the results I wanted, I understand what I was missing now

Comment: @Joshua Reck since the string contains two quotes the split generates three terms and you need the one in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Consider using regular expressions

```py
import re

message = '-400,"Query Error"'
pattern = '(.)([0-9]+),"([^"]*)"'
result = re.match(pattern, message)

symbol = result.group(1)
code = int(result.group(2))
text = result.group(3)

print(f'symbol: {symbol}\ncode: {code}\ntext: {text}')
```

Here `pattern` defines 3 groups indicated by brackets.

1. First group contains a single character, as `.` matches any character.
2. Second group contains a sequence of one or more digits
3. Third group contains any number of characters other than a quotation mark in quotes. Quotes are excluded from the group.